# Metodo de ordenacion Sort de la interfaz List Java

Tags: java

Qué tipo de ordenación hace el metodo sort de una colleccion tipo List? Y que complejidad tiene??(nlogn, n, ...)

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio OKOK!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué esperas como "intento" en una pregunta sobre sobre la implementación del API de Java?

Answer (score -1):

`java.util.List` es una interfaz, pero desde Java 8 las interfaces pueden proveer de una implementación por defecto de un método. Puesto que [`sort(Comparator<? super E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) es un método que se ha añadido en Java 8, para mantener compatibilidad con código antiguo se ha añadido una implementación por defecto que usa una variante del algoritmo [mergesort](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_por_mezcla), que es de complejidad O(n log n).

Esta variante es conocida como [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (no hay entrada en castellano, lo siento) por el nombre de su creador, Tim Peters, un gurú de Python. No es más rápida que el Mergesoft clásico pero optimiza el uso de memoria.

El algoritmo es el mismo que usan los métodos estático `Collections.sort(List<E> list)` y `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`, que ya existían anteriormente a Java 8

Answer (score -2):

Esos datos están especificados en la documentación de Java sobre [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), dentro de `Sort`:

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons.

Traducción:

> Nota de Implementación: Esta implementación es un mergesort estable, adaptativo e iterativo que requiere bastante menos de `n lg(n)` comparaciones cuando el array de entrada está parcialmente ordenado, mientras que ofrece el rendimiento de un mergesort tradicional cuando el array de entrada está ordenado aleatoriamente. Si el array de entrada está casi ordenado, la implementación requiere aproximadamente `n` comparaciones.

Comment: el algoritmo como tal es `n lg(n)`, asumiendo un acceso constante `O(1)` a los miembros de la colección lo cuál sabemos que depende del backend. En general, si una colección tiene un tiempo de acceso `f(n)`, entonces el algoritmo tiene una complejidad `O(f(n) * n lg(n))`